# How to Check if ping utility is present in pod

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes

I want a command to check if ping utility is present in a pod i tried this

```
kubectl exec -it auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu -n kube-system -c etcd-auxiliary-0 ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 ; echo $?
```

Response is.

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container 1 is not valid for pod auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu
1
```

Is there any other better to just check if ping utility is already present or installed in a kubernetes pod.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is incorrect, it is not able to identify the difference between the command to run inside the pod(`ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 ; echo $?`) and the command to run on the host(`kubectl exec -it auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu -n kube-system -c etcd-auxiliary-0`). The right command will be:

```
kubectl exec -it auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu -n kube-system -c etcd-auxiliary-0 -- ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 ; echo $?
```

The above command will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check if command is present/installed inside the `POD`

`kubectl exec -it auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu -- which ping ; echo $?`

This will give you exit status `1` if it doesn't exist.

Also

`kubectl exec -it auxiliary-etcd-ubuntu -- whereis ping`

Which will provide a path to install location.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 && echo "PING PONG" || echo "PING FAILED"
```